# E4X: List document namespaces?

Tags: xml, e4x

How would I get a list of namespaces in an XML document using E4X?

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922668/e4x-grab-nodes-with-namespaces

Comment: Also this would help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080947/xml-namespaces-and-e4x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [namespaceDeclarations() method](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/33393/1954) to get an array of namespaces:

```
var bar = new XML('<html:div xmlns:html="about:html"><p></p></html:div>');
bar.namespaceDeclarations().toString(); //about:html
```

**References**

- [Providing XML to Controls with E4X (pdf)](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flex/articles/training_e4x/e4x.pdf)