# What does :: in an E4X XML statement do?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

I have this XML and a statement of code is doing this call:

```
var rootStory:XML = new XML(source);
var xml:XML = rootStory..*::TextFlow[0];
```

What does this line do, `rootStory..*::TextFlow[0]`?

**UPDATE**:
This was the comment that was with it:

```
// Also note the use of "..*" below. We are using this to traverse the
// XML structure looking for particular tags and at the same time allow for
// any namespace. So, you might see something like <flow:TextContainer> or
// <TextContainer> and this code will capture both cases.
```

So it seems it is either looking for the string, "::" or is it that "::" is an operation like ".."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::` follows the namespace portion of the query. Therefore, `*::` is requesting results from any namespace.

This post may also be helpful: [E4X: grab nodes with namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922668/e4x-grab-nodes-with-namespaces)

Comment: So then we can infer that this seems to be the delimiter between the namespace and node name.